# Unable to disable Home Button

Tags: android, android-homebutton

I am trying to disable home button but getting an error that I don't understand.I have tried many code to disable Home Button but did not got success. This code seems to be better but this error crashes my application. As my application opens and goes to InputPassword Activity it crashes. My homeLockKey code is as follows:

```
public class HomeKeyLocker {
private OverlayDialog mOverlayDialog;

public void lock(Activity activity) {
    if (mOverlayDialog == null) {
        mOverlayDialog = new OverlayDialog(activity);
        mOverlayDialog.show();
    }
}

public void unlock() {
    if (mOverlayDialog != null) {
        mOverlayDialog.dismiss();
        mOverlayDialog = null;
    }
}

private static class OverlayDialog extends AlertDialog {

    public OverlayDialog(Activity activity) {
        super(activity, R.style.OverlayDialog);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.type = TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
        params.dimAmount = 0.0F; // transparent
        params.width = 0;
        params.height = 0;
        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        getWindow().setFlags(FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, 0xffffff);
        setOwnerActivity(activity);
        setCancelable(false);
    }

    public final boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionevent) {
        return true;
    }

    protected final void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        FrameLayout framelayout = new FrameLayout(getContext());
        framelayout.setBackgroundColor(0);
        setContentView(framelayout);
    }
}
```

My activity is :

```
public class InputPassword extends AppCompatActivity {
  HomeKeyLocker homeKeyLocker;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input_password);

    homeKeyLocker = new HomeKeyLocker();
    homeKeyLocker.lock(this);
     }
    }
```

My logcat is :

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rutabaazmat.lockpattern/com.example.rutabaazmat.lockpattern.InputPassword}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@1abfe808 -- permission denied for this window type
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
 Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@1abfe808 -- permission denied for this window type
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:704)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:289)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:311)
    at com.example.rutabaazmat.lockpattern.HomeKeyLocker.lock(HomeKeyLocker.java:27)
    at com.example.rutabaazmat.lockpattern.InputPassword.onCreate(InputPassword.java:39)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
```

Thanks for help in advance:).

Comment: the error says you are missing some permission, but there is one thing you should know - you should not be able to disable home button. It is up to user when to minimize your app, you should not prevent it.

Comment: Please note: what you are trying to achieve is explicitly forbidden by the Play Store policy.
https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/deceptive-behavior/#!#unauthorized-system-functionality

Comment: You are right Vladyslav I was unable to disable button :(. Is there any way I can do it? Because play store have many lock screen applications in which this button is disabled. How they did that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this permission in AndroidManifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```